# RxJS: Use of subjects to update ui

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have a service in which I created a Subject that is in charge of notifying about received resources:

```
@Injectable()
export class ResourceService {

    resourcesSubject: BehaviorSubject<IResource[]>;

    constructor(private requestHandler: RequestHandlerService) {
        this.resourcesSubject = new BehaviorSubject<IResource[]>([]);
    }

    getResources() {
        return this.http.get('/resources')
            .subscribe((resources: IResource[]) => {
                this.resourcesSubject.next(resources);
            });
    }

    addResource() {
        // add resource
        this.getResources()
    }


}
```

I subscribe to this subject in a UI component expecting to receive changes in the resources list whenever the subject does `next`.

This how it looks like in the component:

```
this.resourceService.resourcesSubject.subscribe(resources => {
            console.log(resources);
            this.resources = resources;
        });
}
```

But the `subscribe` only happens once, and not on each triggering of `addResource()`.

How can I get the resources in the component to update every time I submit the call to the server?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: subscribe happens not only once

Comment: is `this.resourcesSubject.next(resources);` being called?

Comment: Do you see new http requests in the devtools console?

Comment: as you can see in the plunker, your example works fine: http://plnkr.co/edit/a8eJOwrsheWGuC8z6vRr

Make sure that `addResource()` is really called.

Furthermore, make sure that your ResourceService is registered only one. Otherwise, you will have multiple instances of ResourceService.

Comment: @Sebastian the problem that I registered `ResourceService` on the components providers and not on the module. Thank you very much!!